# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined , ngx-charts

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-charts

I had previously asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533471/loop-data-and-draw-chart-ngx-line-chart) 
finally I found the solution but there is a problem on the graph we must have 4 charts lines displayed but nothing is displayed,
the first chart line (orders series) is the problem and nothing charts lines appears. 
however, when I disabled the others (3 others charts line) and enable the first chart line , only first chart line appears.

in my browser console it's appear :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
>       at XAxisTicksComponent.tickFormat (index.js:6489)
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (XAxisTicksComponent.html:5)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11948)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11320)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:11556)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11519)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11316)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:11556)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11498)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11321)

after searching to fix it i added in my .html file :

```
[xAxisTickFormatting]='xAxisTickFormatting'
```

and in my .ts file :

```
xAxisTickFormatting(val: string): string {
console.log(this.ticks);
}
```

**console.log(this.ticks)** return :

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvRSG.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Kdy.png)

here is my code in .ts file  :

```
dataChart: any[] = [   
     {
      'name': 'orders',
      'series': []
    },
    {
      'name': 'invoices',
      'series': []
    },
    {
      'name': 'customers',
      'series': []
    },
    {
      'name': 'products',
      'series': []
    }
  ];



 private loadChart() {
    this.service.getChartData().subscribe(
     res => { console.log(res['data']);

  if (res['status_code'] === 200) {

let invoices= res['data'][0]['serieInvoices'];
let orders= res['data'][0]['serieOrders'];
let customers= res['data'][0]['serieCustomers'];
let products= res['data'][0]['serieProducts'];
let i  :number;

for (i=0;i<orders.length;i++){
      this.dataChart[0].series.push({
    'name':  orders[i]['date'],
    'value': orders[i]['nbre'] ,
}); 
}

for (i=0;i<invoices.length;i++){
      this.dataChart[1].series.push({
    'name': invoices[i]['date'],
    'value': invoices[i]['nbre'] ,
});

}

for (i=0;i<customers.length;i++){
      this.dataChart[2].series.push({
    'name': customers[i]['date'],
    'value': customers[i]['nbre'] ,
});

}

for (i=0;i<products.length;i++){
      this.dataChart[3].series.push({
    'name': products[i]['date'],
    'value': products[i]['nbre'] ,
});

}

this.dataChart = [...this.dataChart];
}

},
  err => {

}
)
}
```

here is my code in .html file :

```
<div class="col-xxl-12">
      <nb-card class="card-coubes" style="height:auto;">
        <nb-card-body>
          <ngx-charts-line-chart
                    [view]="view"
                    [scheme]="colorScheme"
                    [results]="dataChart"
                    [gradient]="gradient"
                    [xAxis]="showXAxis"
                    [yAxis]="showYAxis"                                     
                    [legend]="showLegend"
                    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
                    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
                    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
                    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
                    [autoScale]="true"
                    [timeline]="timeline"
                    (select)="onSelect($event)">
          </ngx-charts-line-chart>
        </nb-card-body>
      </nb-card>
</div>
```

how resolve the issue ?

help me please .

thank you in advance

Comment: Is the problem this.ticks array having an undefined item at index 0?

Comment: yes that's the problem

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code where you create the array this.ticks?

Comment: @Aragorn ,Excuse me, I edited my post , i added  my code

Comment: Looked at the code, I still don't see any code where this.ticks is defined or created.

Comment: @Aragorn, but in the browser console it 's appear: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined at XAxisTicksComponent.tickFormat (index.js:6489) ...**

Comment: to fix it , i added in my .ts file : **xAxisTickFormatting function** (see my post )

Comment: @Aragorn , read again my post